# how to implicitly `git push` from a local branch "X" to "origin/Y"

Tags: git, git-push, git-config

Say you have a branch on your origin that has a ridiculously long name...

```
$> git branch -a
* master
  origin/master
  origin/branch-with-a-ridiculously-long-name
```

And when you work on that branch locally, you want to give it a less ridiculous name, like `bob`.

```
$> git checkout origin/branch-with-a-ridiculously-long-name
$> git checkout -b bob
$> git branch --set-upstream bob origin/branch-with-a-ridiculously-long-name
```

When it comes time to push, what can you do such that if you run:

```
$> git checkout bob
$> git push
```

then any local changes on "bob" will be sent to the "branch-with-a-ridiculously-long-name", and won't create a new branch on origin called "bob"?

I'm effectively after a way of making `git push` implicitly expand in to `git push origin bob:branch-with-a-ridiculously-long-name`.

I think setting `git config push.default upstream` goes part of the way, but I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that the local branch's name differs from the remote.

Comment: I think this question has been asked before at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109136/configure-a-local-branch-for-push-to-specific-branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `push.default` to `upstream` (or `tracking` in versions of git before 1.7.4.2), that should do exactly what you want when you run:

```
   git push
```

... or:

```
   git push origin
```

The `git branch --set-upstream` command that you ran, in combination with the config setting, should make that work.

I wrote a post about [this unfortunate asymmetry between git push and git pull](http://longair.net/blog/2011/02/27/an-asymmetry-between-git-pull-and-git-push/).

Comment: Oh man, I was basically at the solution, but I didn't realise it! Thanks, Mark, `push.default` is the secret sauce I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?
http://markmcb.com/2008/09/21/multiple-remote-git-branches-with-different-local-names/

Comment: That's a pretty inventive approach to solving the problem! I'm hoping  there's some nice first-order support that doesn't involve manually editing the config files, but this is good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions of git (most 2.x versions) include the option to set all of this configuration in one command:

```
git checkout -b bob origin/branch-with-a-ridiculously-long-name
```

That will set the upstream of bob to the correct remote branch.

Alternatively if you have a local branch already, you can use the `--set-upstream-to` flag:

```
git checkout bob
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/branch-with-a-ridiculously-long-name
```

Both of these will correctly set the git config