# `Local ref configured for 'git push':` section of `git remote show origin` is not updating

Tags: git, github

I have a branch `sf` locally and a branch `serverfix` on remote.

The output of `git remote show origin`:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:pr0g4amtest1ng/git-remote.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:pr0g4amtest1ng/git-remote.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master    tracked
    serverfix tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
    sf     merges with remote serverfix
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

To make things easy for `git push`, I did the following:

```
git config push.default upstream
git push -u
```

Now if I run `git remote show origin` again

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:pr0g4amtest1ng/git-remote.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:pr0g4amtest1ng/git-remote.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master    tracked
    serverfix tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
    sf     merges with remote serverfix
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Strangely **Local ref configured for 'git push':** didn't change at all.
Shouldn't it add an entry like `sf pushes to serverfix (up to date)` or something like that.

But if I do `git push origin sf`, it gives `Everything up-to-date` and it is not creating an `sf` branch on remote anymore, that means it is tracking.

How will I know which branch are being tracked for 'git push' ?
Why there isn't an entry added for **Local ref configured for 'git push':** or when an entry will be added for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You have **two choices**

- First choice:

  `git config remote.origin.push <local_branch_refs>:<remote_branch_refs>`
- Second choice:
  `git config --edit` to edit the `.git/config` file.

  > [remote "origin"]
  >     push = `<local_branch_refs>:<remote_branch_refs>`

---

For your case, it should be:

```
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/sf:/refs/heads/serverfix
```

After that, you can see the updates in **Local ref configured for 'git push'** section by `git remote show origin`.

Answer (score 0):

[push.default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault) = upstream: push **the current branch**…

To list branches with their upstreams: `git branch -vv`.

Comment: then what about the section `Local ref configured for 'git push':` in `git remote show origin`

and if `push.default upstream` is what you said then what about `push.default matching` ?

Comment: about `git branch -vv`, it is not showing the tracking information about `git push` rather for `git fetch`

Comment: matching - push all branches **having the same name on both ends**. By default `git fetch` is configured to fetch the same branches from the same remote as `git push`.

Comment: well you mean the `upstream` and `matching` both will responsible for branches having same name ?

Comment: (I updated my answer.) With `push.default = upstream` you can push branches one by one. With `matching` you can push many but only to branches with the same names. To push many branches to remote branches with different names you should carefully configure branches in `.git/config`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7583091/7976758 and follow links from there.

Comment: your updated answer is correct in their own context but that doesn't answer my question