# git push on branch src refspec does not match any

Tags: git, branch, push

I would like to clone a branch, make a change and push into the same branch.

I'm doing this:

```
mkdir myfolder
cd myfolder
git init
git clone "myurl" -b "mybranch"
git remote add origin "myurl"
edit "myfile.txt"
git add "myfile.txt"
git commit -m "my comment"
git push origin "mybranch"
```

but I got this error:

```
error: src refspec "mybranch" does not match any 
error: failed to push some refs to "myurl"
```

what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 8):

You may explicitly specify to which remote branch you're pushing:

`git push origin myBranch:existing_remote_branch`

Actually it seems that you perform many excessive steps and generally the workflow is much simpler. Also it's worth to check [Configure a local branch for push to specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109136/configure-a-local-branch-for-push-to-specific-branch)

Update:

Assuming git is relatively modern, I would go as follows:

```
git clone "$myurl" "$myfolder"
cd "$myfolder"
git checkout "$mybranch"
git remote set-head origin "$mybranch"
... add and commit your changes here ...
git push origin "$mybranch"
```

I'd like to ask why you created *two* different git repositories, one in "$myfolder" and another in "$myfolder/<project_name>" ? Is that expected behavior? (I can imagine cases when it may be useful, but they're "corner-cases", at best)

Comment: so,  also if I clone just  a branch, it seem in my local repository I am in master. Should I do `git push origin master:mybranch`, right?  what is the simpler workflow?

Comment: hi,  well that's a good point,  thanks a lot for direct me in the right  way. I'll have a look and let you know.
Thanks a lot for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push to a remote branch with a different name than your local branch, separate the local and remote names with a colon:

```
git push origin local-name:remote-name
```

Answer (score 2):

I was creating a new repository in GitLab , and got the same error of :
git push on branch src refspec does not match any

For me, I Solved by running

```
git checkout -b main
```

then

```
git push origin main
```

and that's because when creating a new repository in the default you stand on the  MASTER branch , and all the instruction asked to do all action on branch MAIN , so by switching to running all action on branch MAIN, I solved my problem

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code, so that the next user knows exactly why did this solution worked for you.

Comment: Yes it is, keep it up :)